# Django - I have a stats dashboard, recommendations on how to refresh the dashboard without client having to refresh page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How can I have my stats dashboard refresh automatically with up to date revenue and transactions for the business, without user having to click on the refresh button in their browser. I want a similar implementation to this Bitcoin USD chart on Yahoo Finance, where data changes without refresh: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD

`views.py`

```
@login_required()
def dashboard(request):
        business = get_object_or_404(Business, businessperson=request.user)
        
        return render(request, 'business/dashboard.html', {
                    "business": business,
                    })
```

`dashboard.html`

```
{% extends my_base %}
{% load static %}
<title>Dashboard</title>
  {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<h2>{{business.name}}</h2>

<p>{{business.transactions}}</p>
<p>{{business.revenue}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: With an AJAX request: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Transferring data over a websocket would work too

Comment: @IainShelvington For websockets, would I do that with Django Channels?

Comment: @Padoga using AJAX and just polling an endpoint is probably simpler if you're new to this